# Oracle Apex/PLSQL: Can i use apex data export to store the file into another table as a blob?

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, oracle-apex

I'm trying to figure out how to store the result of an sql query into a blob column.
The current setup:
I am trying to build a "File store" of sorts. Users can upload files, I will then go through those files, edit them and then give them an option to download those edited files. I'm using Oracle Apex to do this.
So the uploaded files are stored as a blob in the database table, this is done quite easily with Apex. I would like to edit this file, and store it again as a blob in the table.
Basically, I just need to reverse the upload functionality but it doesn't seem to be quite straightforward.

The code roughly likes this:

> 

```
DECLARE
    l_context apex_exec.t_context; 
    l_export  apex_data_export.t_export;
BEGIN
    l_context := apex_exec.open_query_context(
        p_location    => apex_exec.c_location_local_db,
        p_sql_query   => 'select * from emp' );

    l_export := apex_data_export.export (
                        p_context   => l_context,
                        p_format    => apex_data_export.c_format_pdf );

    apex_exec.close( l_context );

    UPDATE my_table
    SET file_blob = l_export;

EXCEPTION
    when others THEN
        apex_exec.close( l_context );
        raise;
END;
```

This gives me an error 'PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type'. However the documentation mentions that the export function exports a file as a blob.

Is this possible to be achieved with Apex Data Export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `l_export` is of datatype `apex_data_export.t_export`. In the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/APEX_DATA_EXPORT-Data-Types.html#GUID-89148B14-CBD1-48F9-9E83-898EEE765E39) you can see what that datatype is exactly. Record type `apex_data_export.t_export` has a column `content_blob` - maybe you could do

```
 UPDATE my_table
    SET file_blob = l_export.content_clob;
```

I have not done any testing but this is where I'd start.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this! A quick follow up on this - when I run this procedure locally(in SQL developer) the procedure completes successfully but the export doesn't happen. However, when I run the same code inside Oracle Apex (as a script) it runs and exports the file successfully. I'm sure I'm making a really silly mistake but I can't figure it out. Would you have any idea?

Comment: Note, it will be content_blob unless p_as_clob specified with a relevant format

Comment: Thanks @Scott ! I hadn't tested this.

Comment: @tomato, probably you need an apex context to run this code. Create an apex session in pl/sql before running it outside of an apex app (check ```APEX_SESSION.CREATE_SESSION```)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scott and Koen. Are there more in-depth documentation for Apex APIs? It needs the name of an user as one of the parameters - Does this need to map to an actual registered user? It seems I can put anything here and a session will be created. Also not sure of the need of having page number as one of the parameters? I'm aware these might be stupid questions for you guys, so apologies.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/APEX_SESSION.html#GUID-710E9F4F-157C-4EBA-BBA9-3E0B9EE4002A) ?

Comment: While it needs to be a page that exists, you probably don't need it for certain tasks. It can be helpful when debugging page behaviour. The username doesn't appear to be validated - sometimes I too wish the documentation had a little more detail.