# Oracle Apex export not exporting file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

This is a follow up on this: [Oracle Apex/PLSQL: Can i use apex data export to store the file into another table as a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75664006/oracle-apex-plsql-can-i-use-apex-data-export-to-store-the-file-into-another-tab)

When I run this procedure locally(in SQL developer) the procedure completes successfully but the export doesn't happen. However, when I run the same code inside Oracle Apex (as a script) it runs and exports the file successfully. I'm sure I'm making a really silly mistake but I can't figure it out.
Any ideas?

Comment: Even if it is a follow up question, when asking questions is better to provide the full context to understand what you are asking, providing the link might lead to misunderstandings about what you are asking now, and lead to answers to your previous question instead of the new problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I execute your PL/SQL, I receive the following message:

```
ORA-20001: This procedure must be invoked from within an application session.
```

So you can remedy this by spoofing a session in SQL Developer using

```
exec apex_session.create_session(100, 1, 'blah')
```

When I replace your update statement with this, I see a value returned

```
dbms_output.put_line('size:'||Dbms_lob.getlength(l_export.content_blob));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott! Apart from the official doc https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/CREATE_SESSION-Procedure.html - are there any other more in-depth guides for this? I'm keen to learn more about the user and page number parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I've seen or remembered. It's a nifty debugging tool, or a workaround for scenarios like this.